# PHP Error in generating unique code for every exist user

Tags: php

i must generate unique hash code for every user in my database. I use 2 functions:

Here is a query to call all user without this key:

```
public function actionGenerate() {
    $users = User::find()->where('forget_code IS NULL ')->all();
    if($users and count($users) > 0) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $code=$this->getForgetToken((int)$user->id); // here give me the error
            $user->forget_code = $code;
            $user->update(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is other two functions :

```
function getForgetToken($id,$length=32) {
    $token = "";
    $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";

    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++) {
        $token .= $codeAlphabet[$this->crypto_rand_secure($id,0,strlen($codeAlphabet))];
    }
    return $token;
}

function crypto_rand_secure($id,$min, $max) {
    $range = $max - $min;
    if ($range < 1) return $min; // not so random...
    $log = ceil(log($range, 2));
    $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
    $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
    $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
    do {
        $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
        $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
    } while ($rnd > $range);
    return $id + $min + $rnd;
}
```

The error is: [image]
and i do not understand why

Comment: why you write a function to generate a crypto code instead of using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` or `random_bytes()`?

Comment: @user9741470 It's using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`, but OP needs random in range

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `$max` 1 too much, because `strlen()` is 1 ahead of array index (0-based). Subtract 1 from strlen

```
$this->crypto_rand_secure($id, 0, strlen($codeAlphabet) - 1)
```

Comment: yes, i understand. i change it, but this is not help ... still the same error

Answer (score 0):

In function `crypto_rand_secure` you are adding `$id` to your result which sometimes may cause you to get index for table larger than table itself. Your table `$codeAlphabet` has 62 characters so you are searching for number from 0 to 61, but then you add `$id` which may cause to get number larger than 61 (eg. `$rand` is 55 and `$id` is 10 so function `crypto_rand_secure` will retrun 10 + 0 + 55 which is 65 (outside of table).